# Правильное написание.

Tags: пунктуация

Здравствуйте.

Король()дама,туз()валет и т.д.

Ставится ли дефис в названиях комбинаций карт и в других подобных случаях?

Answer (score 2):

А почему не просто запятые? У Пушкина - тройка, семерка, туз!

Comment: Мне кажется,тут перечисление,а не название комбинации.
А если: тройка,семерка()пики.Как в этом случае?
Ведь "пики"-общее свойство двух  карт.

Comment: Семерка пики - знак никакой не нужен. Несогласованное определение, условий для обособления нет.

Comment: И у Пушкина не перечисление, а именно название комбинации.

Comment: Какая же комбинация у Пушкина? В три разных дня играла одна из назначенных карт.

Answer (score 1):

По-моему, в этом случае нужен не дефис, а синтаксический знак - тире

Answer (score 1):

Названия карт могут являться обычными однородными членами, в том числе они могут иметь при себе обобщающее слово, например:

Туз, король, дама, валет, десять составят комбинацию, которая называется  флеш -роял. 
Эту комбинацию составляют следующие карты: туз, король, дама, валет, десять.

С помощью дефиса можно ОБОЗНАЧИТЬ последовательность  (комбинацию) карт, например:  "Туз может рассматриваться как младшая карта для образования последовательности  туз-двойка-тройка-четвёрка-пятёрка". Иногда в этом случае дополнительно используют кавычки, но, скорее всего, в них нет необходимости.

Для названия КОМБИНАЦИИ лучше использовать ДЕФИС, так как это орфографический знак (тире является синтаксическим знаком). К похожим сочетаниям можно отнести следующие сложные слова: вопросы-ответы, хлеб-соль, друзья-приятели. (Тире по правилам рекомендуется применять для обозначения пространственных, временных  или количественных ПРЕДЕЛОВ: поезд Москва  – Владивосток,  отпуск в июле – августе, 8 – 10 авторских листов).

Answer (score 0):

В текстах соответствующей направленности (типа учебников) действительно часто ставится дефис. Видимо, сказалось влияние языка оригинала. Только как правило такой дефис используется не при явных названиях: ("Clubs")T-Д-10, ("Diamonds")Q-J-10-9 и т. д.  - *вместо скобок - значки, тут они не отображаются* Из них и рождаются уже словесные: "туз-король-дама" и проч.
Никакими правилами это не регламентировано, поскольку это условные обозначения под ГОСТЫ не подпадающие.

Но я все же воздержался бы от употребления таких обозначений при вне специальной литературы, к "словесным" вариантам это относится всего более.